# Localization and FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, localization

In my app, I have to support multiple languages, so there is one activity where users can select the language for the app.

The problem is, after selecting language, changing locale, all the controls in those activities which are started using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT are still in the previous language.

So is there a way that I can finish all the ever opened activities after user changing the language?

P/s: I tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and it didn't work

Comment: Is your code, where you set controls depending on user selected language, in `OnCreate()` of activity or `OnResume()`? Make sure its in `OnResume() of activity`.

Comment: It's not just labels of controls, but data that has to be gotten from server as well :(